# How to fix: cannot convert 'uint8_t (*)[50] {aka unsigned char (*)[50]}' to 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}'

Tags: c++, c

Im programming ATMEGA328p for a specific problema. Im using libraries in C and C++.

When I compile the code the present erro apears:

**error: cannot convert 'uint8_t (*)[50] {aka unsigned char (*)[50]}' to 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' for argument '2' to 'void SendXbee(char, uint8_t*)**

My call to function is:

```
uint8_t tempBuffer[50]
SendXbee(_data, &tempBuffer);
```

In library headfile:

```
void SendXbee(char Data, uint8_t *Frame);
```

In .c archive the function is:

```
void SendXbee(char Data, uint8_t* Frame){
.
.
.
xBeeAPI_To_Buffer_From_Frame(&Frame, &transmitFrame);
}
```

What im doing wrong?

Comment: remove the `&`.

Comment: From function call or Frame?

Comment: From the call..

Comment: Arrays naturally *decays* to pointers to their first element (if a pointer is expected). If you use plain `temnpBuffer` it's the same as using `&tempBuffer[0]` (which happens to be of the type pointer to `uint8_t`, i.e. `uint8_t*`). When you use `&tempBuffer` you get a pointer to the *array itself*. Which in your case indeed have the type `uint8_t (*)[50]`.

Comment: Thx for explain guy, this help me to understand others erros. I'm glad for your help.